# Magento use simple product images for configurable products

Tags: configurable-product, image, simple-product

Is it possible to make magento use the image of a simple attached product on configurable products if one exists?

Aka, chose a red bike from the config options and the red image loads, however if no image is attached for the red bike, then show default configurable image

Comment: This feature is also known as **color swatches** and there are a lot of modules that offers such functionality.

Answer (score 2):

As already stated by Amasty in the comments, this feature is called "color swatches" and there are many extensions out there which offer this functionality - though most of them are not for free:

- http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/color-swatches-magento-extension.html
- http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/product-color-swatch.html
- http://ecommerce.aheadworks.com/magento-extensions/product-color-swatches.html
- http://amasty.com/color-swatches-pro.html
- http://www.extensionsmall.com/magento-color-swatch.html
- https://www.iwdextensions.com/magento-color-swatch.html
- http://www.mangoextensions.com/advanced-attributes-swatches-for-magento.html

The guys at Inchoo also wrote an [article](http://inchoo.net/magento/create-a-color-switcher-in-magento/) which explains how to implement it yourself.

You should definitely have a look at the extension [Easylife_Switcher](https://github.com/tzyganu/Switcher), which is for free and developed by the one and only Marius.